# Joining NON NULL with NULL Values

Tags: mysql, sql

Table A

```
+----+-------+--------------+-------+----------+
| Id | EName | Company Code | State |   City   |
+----+-------+--------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | Tom   |     110      |  NC   | Ashville |
|  2 | Dick  |              |       |          |
|  3 | Harry |              |       |          |
|  4 | Tonny |     667      |  MN   | St.pauls |
+----+-------+--------------+-------+----------+
```

Table B

```
+----+-------+--------------+-------+----------+
| Id | EName | Company Code | State |   City   |
+----+-------+--------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | Tom   |    110       |  NC   | Ashville |
|  2 | Dick  |    111       |  MN   | Minesota |     
|  3 | Harry |    112       |  CA   | Oregon   |
+----+-------+--------------+-------+----------+
```

O/p

```
+----+-------+--------------+-------+----------+
| Id | EName | Company Code | State |   City   |
+----+-------+--------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | Tom   |    110       |  NC   | Ashville |
|  2 | Dick  |    111       |  MN   | Minesota |     
|  3 | Harry |    112       |  CA   | Oregon   |
|  4 | Tonny |    667       |  MN   | St.pauls |
+----+-------+--------------+-------+----------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT Ename,   
       COALESCE(A.ID, B.ID) AS ID
FROM   `Table A` AS A,
       `Table B` AS B 
WHERE  A.`id_column_1`=B.`id_column_1` 
UNION ALL      
SELECT `Ename,`ID`  
FROM   `Table B` 
WHERE  `Id` IS NOT NULL
```

because I  want to pick ID from Table B only for records where it doesn’t exist in Table A.Please tell me whats wrong in my query. Thank you.

Comment: What if there are records in `TableB` whose `id` does not exist in `TableA`, do you want them in the resultset or not?

Comment: @ GMB, Yes I need that too. Thank you.

Comment: What are the primary keys of the tables?

Comment: `SELECT a.Id, a.EName, b.company_code
b.State, b.City
FROM TableA as a left join TableB as b on a.Id=b.id`
is this what you want?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @newtechy Stop **demanding** help. This is a volunteer site, if somebody has an answer to give you, they will. And please don't abuse the "Rude or Abusive" flags to flag answers that didn't work for you.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to pull the missing information in `a` from `b`.  If so:

```
select a.id,
       coalesce(a.name, b.name) as name,
       coalesce(a.company, b.company) as company,
       coalesce(a.state, b.state) as state,
       coalesce(a.city, b.city) as city
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: So UNION ALL will not work for the o/p I am looking ?

Comment: The query ran for 10 mins. and at end it crashed. Did not run. What  is wrong in UNION ALL ?

Comment: @newtechy . . . Unless your tables are quite large and have many duplicate `id`s, then this should work fine.

Comment: Yes tables are very large and they are multiple company code which are repetitive. Ofcourse ID_1 is unique.

Comment: @newtechy . . . It is irrelevant if company codes are repeated, as long as the `join` keys are unique in the two tables.  If the query in your question runs, this should run *faster*.